# Color row based on DataGridViewComboBoxColumn selection

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridviewcolumn, datagridcomboboxcolumn, datagridviewcombobox

I'm using C# in Visual Studio 2010. I have a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn bound to a DataSource. I would like for when a selection is made from the combobox, the entire row to change color. I'm not sure how to do this because the comboboxes don't have their own separate names, they all fall under cbColumn1. I used this article here but not sure how to make the code work. [How do I immediately change the row color when the selected index of a DataGridViewComboBox changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800553/how-do-i-immediately-change-the-row-color-when-the-selected-index-of-a-datagridv)

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am on my mac but I think you will need to define style for your DataGridRow and put trigger there data trigger which will work on viewmodel.selected item and datagrid row selection state, so it the row is selected and combobox selection value changes the the background changes

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work...you might have to tweak it a little because I tested it on my own program that may be set up rather differently.

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
column.Items.Add("0");
column.Items.Add("1");
column.Items.Add("2");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);



private void dataGridView1_EditingControlShowing(object sender, DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 1)
        {
            ComboBox comboBox = e.Control as ComboBox;
            comboBox.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown;
            comboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
    }


void comboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int selectedIndex = ((ComboBox)sender).SelectedIndex;
        DataGridViewCellStyle style = new DataGridViewCellStyle();
        if (selectedIndex == 0)
        { 
            style.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
        }
        if (selectedIndex == 1)
        {
            style.BackColor = Color.Beige;
        }
        if (selectedIndex == 2)
        {
            style.BackColor = Color.Crimson;
        }
        dataGridView1.CurrentCell.OwningRow.DefaultCellStyle = style;
        dataGridView1.Refresh();
    }
```